# Am I overwriting my linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

*Disclaimer: This is a homework problem. As should be evident, I am trying to solve it myself. I seem to have hit a problem I am unable to figure out, so some help would be appreciated.*

I am required to hash a set of words, and insert it into an array of linked lists. So, if 3 different words have the hash 38, at array[38], I need to have a linked list with the 3 words.

I am using this struct

```
struct Word {
    char* word;
    struct Word* next;
};
```

After I hash, I insert it into the array like this:

```
struct Word* table[1000];   // array of linked-lists

char word[128];
while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict) != NULL) {
    hashValue = hashWord(word, strlen(word));        

    struct Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct Word));
    newWord->word = word;           

    if (table[hashValue] == NULL) {
        table[hashValue] = newWord;             
    } else {   // at index hashValue, table already contains at least one element
        // insert new word as first element of linked-list
        newWord->next = table[hashValue];
        table[hashValue] = newWord;         
    }

}
```

I know there are about 5 words that have a hash of 38, but when I print them, I get the same word 5 times:

```
struct Word* foo = table[38];

while (foo->next != NULL) {
    printf("%s", foo->word); // prints the same word every time
    foo = foo->next;
}
```

It seems I am overwriting my linked list at some point, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: I haven't really done much C since school so I could be totally wrong. But it looks like you are doing `char word[128];` before your loop, and then writing over that same piece of memory every single time you go through the while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict) != NULL) {
    ...
    newWord->word = word;
```

The problem is that you're replacing the contents of `word`, which is the same pointer stored in every `newWord`.

You're allocating a new `Word` structure on the heap each time with this line:

```
struct Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct Word));
```

But this only allocates memory for the `Word` structure itself; the `Word` structure includes a `char *word`—i.e. a pointer to a character (or NUL-terminated string, in this case), but it doesn't actually include any space for the string itself.

You need to explicitly allocate memory for the string, now. Try this:

```
newWord->word = strdup(word);
```

This will put a *copy* of `word` into each `Word` structure. This copy won't be overwritten when `fgets()` next gets called in your `while` loop.  Remember that the stack-allocated character array:

```
char word[128];
```

is only valid while this function is executing; you must allocate something on the heap (with `malloc()`, or something that uses it, like `strdup()`) if you want it to live beyond the function call.

When you're finished, don't forget to `free()` the `char *word`s before freeing each `Word*`.

Comment: But I am malloc'ing newWord in every iteration of the loop. Why does it still overwrite?

Comment: +1 of course strdup and not strcpy... shouldn't answer questions befor my forst coffe.. Also you should newWord->next = null; to show it explicitely

Comment: @xbonez: I'll answer you in the question.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I get what you are saying. I should have seen that myself. Thank you.

Comment: your are mallocing the list node, and the list node does not contain the string, just a pointer to it. and newWord->word = word just sets the pointer and does not copy the content of the string

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the word array. You are only storing pointers to the array, but the array gets overwritten with each new word. You need separate memory to hold each word.